# How To Install Atlassian Connector On Eclipse Photon 4.8.x Version

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I can not download Atlassian connector for eclipse photon 4.8.0 version.

It support Installation via the Eclipse Marketplace for Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo), 4.2 (Juno), 4.3 (Kepler), 4.4 (Luna) But not Photon.

This site is supporting download

https://confluence.atlassian.com/ideplugin/atlassian-connector-for-eclipse/installation-and-upgrade-guide-for-the-eclipse-connector/installing-the-eclipse-connector

How can I plugin it to Photon?

Comment: Does _Help > Install New Software..._ working with the update site [`http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7/`](http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7/) solves your issue?

Comment: @howlger I used your url It can not work.  After I downloaded Mylyn JIRA Connector should work in Eclipse Photon JEE https://github.com/rastaman/jira-mylyn-connector/releases

Comment: It is work to me

Comment: Has anyone had success with the forked connector in rastaman's github in the above comment, for recent versions (March 2021) of Eclipse and JIRA Cloud? The version from the Atlassian update site was still working for me for Jira on-prem but gives an error for Jira Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Although the development of the plug-in has been discontinued, the Atlassian connector can still be installed as follows:

- In ***Help > Install New Software...*** work with the update site [**`http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7/`**](http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/rest/e3.7/)